# Политика доступа к коду родительской страницы из iframe

Tags: html, iframe, javascript

Добрый день.

Интересует следующий вопрос: какова политика доступа к javascript функциям и переменным родителя для iframe. Если и target iframe и его родитель находятся на одном домене, то никаких проблем не возникает:

```
parent.function();
```

а вот если на разных поддоменах одного сайта: sub.domain.com и sub2.domain.com, то выскакивает сообщение с попыткой доступа к защищённой переменной function().

Это особенность политики iframe или я что-то делаю не так? И, если особенность, не могли бы Вы дать пример реализации?

Answer (score 1):

политика безопасности это точно. Сам столкнулся с этим и очень долго понять не мог, а встретилось это только на изучении JS. Подробнее [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: подробнее здесь: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

а лучше на английском читайте, эту же статью: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy